# Specifying arguments in C# Process

Tags: c#, process

In Java, when I want to start a process, I can just tell it the commands to run:

```
String[] commands = {"Perl", "-e", "print \"hello world\""}
ProcessBuilder processBuild = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuild.command(commands);
```

In C#, I have a problem because I need to do the same thing but I have to fill out `filename` and `arguments` separately as individual strings:

```
processBuild.FileName = commands[0];
for (int x = 1; x < commands.Length; x++)
{
    processBuild.Arguments += " " + commands[x];

}
```

Now I don't know what the user is going to be trying to invoke, so I can't tailor this to fit the intended program. The problem with my above solution is that the process tries to run `perl -e print "hello world"`. Why does it force me to treat this like a command line?

Of course I can't do something like `if !start with [-/] { Surround with quotes }` because then something like "cmd /c echo hello" gets turned into `cmd /c "echo" "hello"`. I mean I suppose I could make a bunch of if/elses and try to be smart about it, but there must be a better way?

So I turn to you guys to help me out. How can I kick off a process in C# that specifies its arguments in a non-cmd line fashion?

Answer (score 1):

The Process class used the CreateProcess API under the hood which is one of the lowest-level APIs available to start a process. This API separates executable from arguments, because it would have the same difficulties telling them apart as you do.

Two solutions:

- Start cmd.exe as a process and hand your "command" as the argument to
  it. cmd.exe will do the parsing for you.
- Do the parsing yourself although it is difficult.

Comment: That still requires knowing how to create a valid argument string (which can then be parsed into a list of arguments).  There's no way to just provide the list of arguments in the first place (a la Unix's `execv` or `execvp`) so that no knowledge of relevant quoting is required?